# Toubleshoot the expensive queries by Finding the queries with its executionplan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-administration

The query below displays everything that was helpful to a DBA except the database name. I was looking for the another version of this which should display the database name.

```
SELECT TOP 10 DatabaseName = DB_Name(t.dbid),
                        sql_text = SUBSTRING (t.text, qs.statement_start_offset/2,
                                    (CASE WHEN qs.statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), t.text)) * 2
                                    ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2),
                        ObjectName = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.objectid,t.dbid) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(t.objectid, t.dbid),
                        qs.execution_count AS [Executions], qs.total_worker_time AS [Total CPU Time],
                        qs.total_physical_reads AS [Disk Reads (worst reads)],  qs.total_elapsed_time AS [Duration], 
                        qs.total_worker_time/qs.execution_count AS [Avg CPU Time],qs.plan_generation_num,
                            qs.creation_time AS [Data Cached], qp.query_plan
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs WITH(NOLOCK) 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS t
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle) AS qp 
        ORDER BY DatabaseName, qs.total_worker_time DESC;
```

Comment: try this one: https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. The builtin DB_Name function should be returning the Database Name based on the t.dbid column. When I test it, the query works for me.

Comment: That query will include statements referencing the resource database 32767. if you do `db_name(32767)` it returns `null`. That might explain why you're not seeing a database name for those. However if you exclude those, everything should return a name

Comment: Can you please help me with that Xedni. I'm confused on the thing that you have explained but I understood where you referenced the resource db. I need the query above to display the database name where it was returning the null.